# knapSack problem returning a list of values instead of total value

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

```
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):

    if n == 0 or W == 0:
        return 0

    if (wt[n - 1] > W):
        return knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1)

    else:
        return max(val[n - 1] + knapSack(W - wt[n - 1], wt, val, n - 1),
                   knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1))
```

So far I have this code as my reference.
Is that possible that I can return a list of value instead of returning a total value?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Frank, can you give us your input

Comment: val = [60, 100, 120] 
wt = [10, 20, 30] 
W = 50
n = len(val) something like this

Comment: BTW I strongly believe this "reference code" is incorrect - it accidentally returns the correct result for your example data, but try testing it for `wt=[30,20,10]` instead… it returns 280, which clearly means that it packed all three items, exceeding the weight limit. Or is it an implicit condition that `wt` is sorted in ascending order?

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing this code I came to believe your parameters are: W - max weight of the knapsack, wt - list of item weights, val - list of item values, n - number of items. I propose a different approach, without using recursion at all, utilizing `powerset` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) instead:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def weight(subset): # returns total weight of items in subset
    return sum(i[0] for i in subset)

def value(items): # returns total value of items in subset
    return sum(i[1] for i in subset)

def knapsack(W, items): 
    return max( (subset for subset in powerset(items) if weight(subset) <= W), key=value)

val = [60, 100, 120]
wt = [10, 20, 30]
W = 50

print(knapsack(W, zip(wt, val)))

# prints ((20, 100), (30, 120)) ie. pairs (weight, value) of the best combination
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! 
But I think I have to use recursion to solve this problem.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution I've found, thank you!